# I am trying to create a popup message it always says popupmsg is not defined when it is, what should I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from tkinter import *
import math

NORM_FONT = ("Ariel", 12)


class window(object):  # An object has been created called window
    def __init__(self, root):  # The function root has been initialised

        self.root = root  # This gives root and attribute
        self.root.title("Calculator")
        menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menu)
        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save_calc)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        edit = Menu(menu)
        edit.add_command(label="Change Calc")
        menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)
        file.add_command(label="Save Settings", command=lambda: popupmsg("A text file has been created in the directory"))

    def save_calc(self):  # This save calc method will allow the user to save the calculation they have written
        f = open("Untitled", "w")  # opens a file with a untitled.txt
        self.Save = f.write("Write your previous calculation")
        self.Save = f.close()  # This closes the file

    def popupmsg(msg=""):
        popup = tk.Tk()
        popup.wm_title("!")
        label = tk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        b1 = tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy)
        b1.pack()
        popup.mainloop()


screen = Tk()
window(screen)
screen.geometry("700x400")
screen.mainloop()

print("Hello World")
```

Comment: How many different versions of Python are you using?

Comment: I use version 3 of python

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fix the method `popupmsg` to add the `self` parameter, and to instantiate a `TopLevel` instead of a second `Tk()` (and also remove all the `tk.` that is not defined in your import here)

```
def popupmsg(self, msg=""):
    popup = Toplevel(self.root)
    popup.wm_title("!")
    label = Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    b1 = Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy)
    b1.pack()
    # mainloop is not needed here
```

Then you can call this method in the lambda, with `self.popupmsg` :

```
file.add_command(label="Save Settings", command=lambda: self.popupmsg("A text file has been created in the directory"))
```